# Display a limited number of items on Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, infinite-scroll

Avoid display all item from a json in HTML page with https://infinite-scroll.com/

I'm trying to use the jquery plugin, Infinite Scroll, to build my single page web app, but all the elements stored in the json file are displayed at the same time in my html page and when I click the view more button the display continues reloading the elements from the beginning

How i can limit number of elements display per page or each time i click load more button

### HTML Code

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__col-sizer"></div>
        <div class="grid__gutter-sizer"></div>
    </div>



    <p>
        <button class="view-more-button">View more</button>
    </p>


    <!-- .photo-item template HTML -->
    <script type="text/html" id="photo-item-template">

        <div class="photo-item">
            <img class="photo-item__image" src="{{Images.URL}}" />
            <p class="photo-item__caption">
            </p>
        </div>

    </script>
```

### Javascript Code

```
             var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.photo-item',
            columnWidth: '.grid__col-sizer',
            gutter: '.grid__gutter-sizer',
            percentPosition: true,
            stagger: 30,



            visibleStyle: {
                transform: 'translateY(0)',
                opacity: 1
            },
            hiddenStyle: {
                transform: 'translateY(100px)',
                opacity: 0
            },
        });

        //------------------//

        // Get an API key for your demos at https://unsplash.com/developers
        // var unsplashID = '9ad80b14098bcead9c7de952435e937cc3723ae61084ba8e729adb642daf0251';

        // get Masonry instance
        var msnry = $grid.data('masonry');

        $grid.infiniteScroll({
            path: function() {
                return 'data-amz.json';

            },
            // load response as flat text
            responseType: 'text',
            outlayer: msnry,

            history: true,

            button: '.view-more-button',
            // load pages on button click
            scrollThreshold: false,
            // disable loading on scroll
            // nicer reveal transition


        });

        $grid.on('load.infiniteScroll', function(event, response) {

            // console.log(response)
            // parse response into JSON data
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            // compile data into HTML
            var itemsHTML = data.Product.map(getItemHTML).join('');

            var $items = $(itemsHTML);
            // append item elements
            $items.imagesLoaded(function() {

                $grid.infiniteScroll('appendItems', $items)
                    .masonry('appended', $items);
            })
        });

        // load initial page
        $grid.infiniteScroll('loadNextPage');

        //------------------//

        var itemTemplateSrc = $('#photo-item-template').html();

        function getItemHTML(photo) {
            return microTemplate(itemTemplateSrc, photo);
        }

        // micro templating, sort-of
        function microTemplate(src, data) {
            // replace {{tags}} in source
            return src.replace(/\{\{([\w\-_\.]+)\}\}/gi, function(match, key) {
                // walk through objects to get value
                var value = data;
                key.split('.').forEach(function(part) {
                    value = value[part];
                });
                return value;
            });
        }
```

### JSON data

```
{
    "Product": [
        {
            "Key": {
                "Key": "Value"
            }
        },
        {
            "Key": {
                "Key": "Value"
            }
        },
        {
            "Key": {
                "Key": "Value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If your data source is just one JSON file then perhaps it would be better if you store it in a global variable and use the `loadCount` option to calculate the offset for each new page: https://infinite-scroll.com/api.html#loadcount

Comment: yes just 1 json file, can you show me how i can do that?

Comment: Apologies, I think I've misunderstood how InfiniteScroll works - it looks like the `path` option must always be a URL and doesn't support loading from a variable. How is your JSON file generated? Are you able to create your own endpoint, e.g. something like `www.mywebsite.com/json?page=1`, then `?page=2` etc.?

Comment: i can't accept add it in the JS

Comment: In that case I think InfiniteScroll isn't the right tool for the job here; it relies on having an endpoint like the example I just mentioned. Instead, I'd recommend detecting when the user has reached the bottom of the page then fetching the relevant part of your JSON depending on how many times the user's reached the bottom.

Comment: ok so you think, i need change script, any suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198364/discussion-between-stew-and-user7290573).